# How to prepare phosphate buffer solution from mono- and disodium phosphate with a specific pH?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, concentration

I want to prepare an aqueous solution of a mobile phase of $\pu{0.04M}$ Brij-35. The mobile phase has to be adjusted to pH $7.4$ with $\pu{0.5M}$ phosphate buffer which will be prepared with $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ and $\ce{Na2HPO4}$ solutions.

Can anyone help me to prepare a phosphate buffer solution of $\pu{0.05M}$ using $\ce{NaH2PO4.2H2O}$ and $\ce{Na2HPO4.7H2O}$ with pH $7.4$?

Comment: @fl.pf. The shorter `$\ce{NaH2PO4.2H2O}$` works perfectly fine, mhchem handles quite a lot of shorthand. (I am not saying that that would have been my reason to further edit, but it might help you save some time for future edits. I simply wanted to fix the title in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the [Henderson-Hasselbalch equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation) $(1)$.

$$\mathrm{pH} = \mathrm pK_\mathrm a + \lg\frac{[\ce{HPO4^2-}]}{[\ce{H2PO4-}]}\tag{1}$$

Plugging the $\mathrm pK_\mathrm{a2}$ value of phosphoric acid ($7.198$) and the desired $\mathrm{pH}$ value will give you a ratio of hydrogenphosphate and dihydrogenphosphate concentrations which you can solve to the desired total concentration $c_\text{tot}$ by simple algebra.

However, SigmaAldrich also maintains a nice [buffer reference centre](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/life-science/core-bioreagents/biological-buffers/learning-center/buffer-reference-center.html#NA2HPO4) that includes ready-calculated masses for different $\mathrm{pH}$ values. All that remains is to make sure your final concentration is the desired one.

Comment: as you can see using SigmaAldrich they provided calculations using concentration of 0.2M but mine is o.o5M according to my question above, how can I convert concentration from o.2M to o.o5M ? will I still use the same amount of ml provided ?

Comment: @UHAGAZED.Serge By dividing by four, obviously.

Comment: can you divide concentration (in terms of g/l)by four or you divide volume by four ?